# A Wikipedia page {for/of} a controversial person

Tags: prepositions

Consider the following phrases:

> A Wikipedia page **for** a controversial person.
>
> A Wikipedia page **of** a controversial person.

I am a little confused about which preposition I should use here.

Comment: Neither; I would say **about**.

Comment: @stangdon thank you.

Comment: It all depends on whether you are reading it or creating it. If you are creating it, you'd say, "I made a Wikipedia page for a controversial person," because you did it. If you're just reading it, you'd say, "I read a Wikipedia page of a controversial person." However, what you've posted are two sentence fragments -- you'd never write them as is.

Comment: @FeliniusRex thank you.